# API versioning with inline namespaces

Tags: c++, api-design

I want to introduce a breaking change into the API of a library ([seastar](http://seastar.io)), without breaking users. So I want to provide a way for clients to migrate to the new API at their own pace. For this I'd like to use inline namespaces. The basic idea is simple enough, you introduce a `namespace v1` for the old version and an `inline namespace v2` for the new one (or the other way around). This is described nicely in https://foonathan.net/2018/11/inline-namespaces/. Trouble starts when you want to introduce yet another breaking change, a `namespace v3`. Lets have some example code as a basis for further discussion:

```cpp
namespace v1 {
    int foo(); // old version of foo
}

inline namespace v2 {
    std::string foo(); // new, incompatible version of foo
    int bar(); // old version of bar
}

namespace v3 {
    std::string bar(); // new, incompatible version of bar
}
```

Now if I want to update the default API version to v3, that is make the v3 version of `bar()` be available by default, I can make `namespace v3` `inline`. We have arrived at my dilemma: if I make *only* `v3` `inline` I break my clients who already migrated to use the latest, `v2` version of `foo()` (and hence are using it without the namespace qualifier). If I make both `v2` and `v3` `inline`, so that the latest version of all functions is accessible in the global (library) namespace, I introduce an ambiguity between `v3::bar()` and `v2:bar()`. If I move `v2::foo()` to `v3`, I break clients who just started migrating to `v2::foo()` and are using it with the fully qualified name (`::v2::foo()`). Another option is to re declare all the latest version of functions in the namespace corresponding to the latest API version and make only that `inline`. This is a lot of repetition and some extra generated code. Is there a more elegant solution?

I've been also suggested to just to `using v2::bar` (and so on) inside `inline namespace v3` to export the latest version of all symbols into the latest inline namespace. This however breaks ADL as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up settling with a solution that is not as nice and elegant as I wanted it to be but it is simple and it works.
My solution is to introduce two new api versions for each breaking change. In terms of my example from the question I did the following:

```cpp
namespace v1 {
    int foo(); // old version of foo
}

inline namespace v2 {
    std::string foo(); // new, incompatible version of foo

namespace v3 {
    int bar(); // old version of bar
}

inline namespace v4 {
    std::string bar(); // new, incompatible version of bar
}
```

Odd numbered versions stand for the deprecated version of changed symbols, while even numbered versions stand for the new version thereof. This system is scalable, simple and robust, however it is somewhat unintuitive and definitely not elegant.
I have preprocessor macros in place that allows the clients to select the default "api version". For example if a client is not yet ready to use the latest API, it can select API version 3, after which namespaces v2 and v3 will be inline. Afther they migrated to the latest API, they can bump the API version to 4, which will result in the state seen above.